# Convert tradingview's pine script to python in VScode

Tags: python, api, visual-studio-code, binance, tradingview-api

I want to convert the following Pine script to python to calculate the value for vwap1 variable without plotting the results, I just want to calculate the value for vwap1:

```
...
wapScore(pds) =>
    mean = sum(volume*close,pds)/sum(volume,pds)
    vwapsd = sqrt(sma(pow(close-mean, 2), pds) )
    (close-mean)/vwapsd

vwap1 = input(48)
plot(vwapScore(vwap1),title="ZVWAP2-48",color=#35e8ff, linewidth=2,transp=0.75)
...
```

I have tried the following:

```
...
def calculate_SMA(ser, days):
    sma = ser.rolling(window=days).mean()
    return sma


def calculate_Zscore(pds, volume, close):
    mean = sum(volume * close, pds) / sum(volume, pds)
    vwapsd = np.sqrt(calculate_SMA(pow(close - mean, 2), pds))
    return (close - mean) / vwapsd

...
```

And I am using `calculate_Zscore` function to calculate the value and add it to pandas dataframe but it gives me different values rather than the values on trading view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wanted to comment ...but my reputation cannot allow me :)

Surely the `sum` of pine script (tradingview) has a different type signature than the python `sum`.
In particular the second parameter has a totally different meaning.
In pine script `sum(x,y)` tells you the sliding sum of last y values of x (sum of x for y bars back).
In python `sum(x,y)` sum the iterable `x` and if `y`, the second parameter has passed (optional), this value is added to the sum of items of the iterable.So if your `sum(x)` == 4.5 then `sum(x,10)` == 14.5

So your code surely need to be changed at least on the use of this method

Hoping to be helpful

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30722438)

Comment: Exactly, I just wanted to post a comment but I couldn't so I preferred to answer the question because it clearly gives information to put the questioner to the right path or at least warn him/her about a clear error